# How can I select an image from another folder?

Tags: php, html

I have two folders in the root folder (`Admin` and `Users`). Now I'm working on a file in the `Users` folder, and want to display user's details when they login. The images were saved in the `Admin` folder, so how do I call the image from the `Admin` folder for it to be displayed on a page in the `Users` folder?

This is what I tried, but it didn't work:

```
<img SRC="/Admin/images/<?php echo $user_pic ; ?>" class="img-rounded" />
```

I also tried with two dots in front of admin but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: <img SRC="/Admin/images/<?php echo $user_pic ; ?>" class="img-rounded" />

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the following file tree.

```
Root
  Users
  Admins
```

If you are in root, and want to access an image inside the admins folder, path would either be

```
admin
```

Or a relative path

```
/admin
```

If you are in the admin folder, wanting to acres the users folder, you need to backtrack folders. You can do this by doing ../

```
../users
```

This would go to root and then users.

Comment: Thanks George. I'll give it a try and see how it goes

Comment: Hello George, thanks once again. It worked very fine